# how to convert t_sql to linq and lambda?

Tags: sql, linq, lambda

How can I convert the following code to linq and lambda?

```sql
SELECT array_agg(plc) AS _plc FROM(
      SELECT 
            plc.id AS _order,
            '{"id": ' || plc.id || ', "key": "' || plc.key || '", "text": "' || plc.text || '", "other": "' || plc.other || '"}' AS plc,
            '{"id": ' || sub.id || ', "key": "' || sub.key || '", "text": "' || sub.text || '", "img_url": "' || sub.img_url || '"}' AS sub
      FROM public.places plc
      LEFT JOIN  public.sub_places sub ON plc.value = sub.key
      ORDER BY plc.id
) foo GROUP BY plc, _order 
ORDER BY _order
```

thank you

Comment: Probably you don't have to generate JSON by SQL. Before this question is closed, show your class model, specify which ORM do you use, which version, which data provider and what you expect at the end.

Comment: as i see you try to create a json from sql. did you try to use OPENJSON ?